# RuntimeError from python multiprocessing pools with joinable queues

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am seeing RunTime errors on exit when using two multiprocessing.Pool's each with a different joinable queue's. Below is a simple code example showing the issue.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

q_1 = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
q_2 = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

def process():
    pool_1 = multiprocessing.Pool(1, worker_1,(q_1,))
    pool_2 = multiprocessing.Pool(1, worker_2,(q_2,))
    for i in range(3):
        q_1.put(i)
    q_1.join()
    q_2.join()
    pool_1.close()
    pool_2.close()

def worker_1(input_q):
    while True:
        val = input_q.get(True)
        print("1:"+str(val))
        q_2.put(val)
        input_q.task_done()

def worker_2(input_q):
    while True:
        val = input_q.get(True)
        time.sleep(2)
        print("2:"+str(val))
        input_q.task_done()
```

When this exits i get the following error

```
Exception RuntimeError: RuntimeError('cannot join current thread',) in <Finalize object, dead> ignored
```

I have two environments available to me, on

Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, python 2.7.3 - I get the error.

RHEL 6.3, python 2.6.6 - I do not get the error.

Searching around most suggestions involved joining on the pool after close(), but if I do that the process never exits. Also all examples I have found only have one pool, not two or more (using a single pool/queue doesn't produce the error).

Any ideas with what's causing this error?

Comment: After some experimentation it is definately related to the python version.Running on Ubuntu with python 2.6.9 or 2.7.5 works fine, only 2.7.3 fails, which is the Ubuntu version of python.